# What are these tiny, bouncy balls I found in my Calathea substrate?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I found two of these small eggs/seeds (?) in the substrate of the Calathea plant I just bought from a botany store. I cut one of them open to make sure it's not just plastics or similar.

[image]

- About 4 mm across
- Quite bouncy
- It looks like they have something a little darker on the one side of the sphere, and the other side seems a little bit transparent
- When cutting it open it was a little "crusty"

I looked up what Calathea seeds look like, definitely not like this. Any idea what this could be?

Comment: Since these are the non-organic fertiliser beads used when filling the pot (a few are sprinkled in before selling to slow-release nutrients) and not something biological such as snail-eggs, this question would be off-topic here. If you're interested in knowing more about them, check-out the [gardening.se] site which specialises in related stuff.